# How to do power law test for DMSP/OLS nighttime Satellite data

Tags: remote-sensing, spatial-statistics, statistics

I am working with DMSP/OLS satellite's (6 bit) nighttime light data to study the urban expansion of different cities in South Asia. I could not understand the Power law distribution method. I searched over the internet but didn't get how to do that, hence can anyone here help me with that ? The pixel data and the number of a particular pixel occurrences for one city is as follows:

```
Pixel_VALUE COUNT
3   3
4   14
5   57
6   163
7   182
8   126
9   79
10  80
11  71
12  56
13  67
14  42
15  30
16  30
17  37
18  26
19  23
20  16
21  14
22  16
23  18
24  12
25  20
26  12
27  7
28  10
29  11
30  8
31  21
32  15
33  14
34  12
35  17
36  11
37  9
38  19
39  8
40  12
41  7
42  11
43  16
44  10
45  12
46  8
47  10
48  10
49  7
50  14
51  6
52  12
53  6
54  8
55  13
56  6
57  13
58  10
59  17
60  15
61  23
62  41
63  177
```